# How to get an element to change with a dropdown in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am currently developing a eBay application for BlackBerry 10 and have come across a problem. The problem is, is that I would like to have a dropdown menu (so the user can select which eBay country they want access) but I do not know how to get a button at the bottom of the screen to go to the correct page when an option has been selected in the dropdown.

http://i1078.photobucket.com/albums/w483/tobster619/Blackberry%2010/help_zps923bcc21.png

Here's is a broken down version of the code, that can be seen in the attached image:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//verify the welcome screen 
function verifywelcome(){ 
if (document.getElementById('checkbox').get... == true) { 
alert('checkbox is checked'); 
//set the localstorage item 
localStorage.welcome = "true" ; 
} else if (document.getElementById('checkbox').get... == false) { 
alert('checkbox is not checked'); 
//set the localstorage item 
localStorage.welcome = "false"; 
} 
} 
//if you want to remove the localStorage key to redisplay the welcome screen again.    use: localStorage.removeItem('welcome'); 
function welcome() { 
//check if welcome exists, if not: create it 
if (localStorage.welcome == null) { localStorage.welcome = "true" }; 
if (localStorage.getItem('welcome') == "true") /* if it is true: */ { 
bb.pushScreen('welcome.html', 'welcome'); 
} 
else if (localStorage.getItem('welcome') == "false") { 
bb.pushScreen('menu.html', 'menu'); 
} 
} 

//verify the welcome screen 
function verifywelcome2(){ 
if (document.getElementById('checkbox').get... == true) { 
alert('checkbox is checked'); 
//set the localstorage item 
localStorage.welcome = "true" ; 
} else if (document.getElementById('checkbox').get... == false) { 
alert('checkbox is not checked'); 
//set the localstorage item 
localStorage.welcome = "false"; 
} 
} 


//if you want to remove the localStorage key to redisplay the welcome screen again. use: localStorage.removeItem('welcome'); 
function welcome() { 
//check if welcome exists, if not: create it 
if (localStorage.welcome == null) { localStorage.welcome = "true" }; 
if (localStorage.getItem('welcome') == "true") /* if it is true: */ { 
bb.pushScreen('welcome.html', 'welcome'); 
} 
else if (localStorage.getItem('welcome') == "false") { 
bb.pushScreen('menu2.html', 'menu2'); 
} 
} 
function onLoadFunctions() { 
// Register the app. Make sure you get a unique UUID! 
blackberry.event.addEventListener('ona... function (accessible, status) { 
if (status === 'unregistered') { 
blackberry.bbm.platform.register({ 
uuid: 'b1e606e8-66e5-41db-a932-6ad42f2aa59c' 
}); 
} else if (status === 'allowed') { 
bbm.registered = accessible; 
} 
}, false) 
} 
</script> 

<select id="countryselector"> 
<option value="eBay UK" selected="true" onchange="verifywelcome();bb.pushScreen(...  'Menu');onLoadFunctions();">eBay UK</option> 
<option value="eBay US" "verifywelcome2();bb.pushScreen('menu2.h... 'Menu2');onLoadFunctions();">eBay US</option> 
<option value="eBay CA">eBay CA</option> 
</select> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<td class="cell" style="margin-top:13px;">Show this page on launch</td> 
<td class="cell" ><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="true" value="one"/>    </td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<!--BOTTOM PAGE MENU BAR --> 
<div data-bb-type="action-bar"> 
<div data-bb-type="action" data-bb-style="button" data-bb-img="IMG/ic_next.png"  onclick="verifywelcome();bb.pushScreen('... 'Menu');onLoadFunctions();">The Native eBay Experience Awaits...</div> 
</div>
```

So, when the user clicks the button (the last part of the code that I have just shown you) it will take them to eBay UK (menu.html) and my question to you is: how do I get that to change if the user was to select eBay US (menu2.html) and when they click the button it takes them to menu2.html (eBay US) instead of menu.html (eBay UK) whilst still allowing the different onclick functions to work ("verifywelcome();verifywelcome2();onLoadFunctions();")?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could define the `onchange` event at the `select` level (rather than the `option` level) and make the values of the options the respective pages they correspond to. Then the handler for `onchange` will set the button's `click` handler to something like `document.location = this.value` (where `this` is the `countryselector` element.

I have never programmed in the Blackberry DOM, so I can't write any code. But maybe that gives you an idea.